# lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError, Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content

Tags: python, xml, utf-8, lxml, utf-16

> lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError, Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content

I am getting the error using lxml lib in python. Other solutions/hacks are replacing utf-16 to utf-8 in file php. What is the pythonic way to solve this?

python code:

```
import lxml.etree as etree

tree =  etree.parse("req.xml")
```

req.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<test 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
</test>
```

Comment: what do you want in output?

Comment: I just need to parse that xml, encoding is not important

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation of the `XMLParser` constructor:

```
>>> help(etree.XMLParser)
```

Among other options, there is an `encoding` parameter, which allows you to "override the document encoding", as the docs say.

That's exactly what you need:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='UTF-8')
tree = etree.parse("req.xml", parser=parser)
```

If the error message is right (ie. there aren't any other problems with the document), then I expect this to work.

Answer (score -1):

You can parse xml content using `BeautifulSoup` which is more pythonic way as you required.

> NOTE: If your data is encoded in `utf-16` it can easily parse by decoding in `utf-8` during reading/PARSE the file content.

So below is the code:

sample.xml contains following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<test 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
</test>
```

---

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("sample.xml", "r") as f: # opening xml file
    content = f.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore') # xml content stored in this variable and decode to utf-8

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser') #parse content to BeautifulSoup Module
data = [data.attrsfor data in soup.findAll("test")]
print data
```

---

Output:

```
{u'xmlns:xsi': u'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', u'xmlns:xsd': u'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'}
```

Comment: But... reading the file to memory and passing a decoded string to parse also works with lxml (using `etree.fromstring()`). What's the benefit of using an HTML parser to parse XML here?

Comment: Thanks for answer but this can be achived in lxml like lenz said. No need to use another lib for string decoding.

Comment: @lenz Yes i totally agree with your answer but it was just another approach. that is why i have mention in `NOTE` that you have to decode(`UTF-8`) the content while you parse, which i said in general whatsoever package you use

Comment: I still don't understand why you recommend using an HTML parser. I mean, even BS has an XML parser: `soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'xml')` would be a way of doing the same as the OP with a different library. But why do you explicitly suggest using `'html.parser'`?

Comment: @lenz i didn't suggest to use `beautifulsoup`, it was just an approach.